# Facebook JSON output

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I have this code

```
    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/100000070848126/statuses?access_token=".$params['access_token'];
    $status = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url),true);

    echo $status->data->message;
```

and I'm having a problem on how to output data in the array $status. I just don't know how to call the items for this feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is whether to create an associative array or not.

> `json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false])`

You specified that you **do** want an array, so the way you would access the values would be like this -

```
echo $status['data']['message'];
```

If you leave out the `true` parameter of the `json_decode()` function, you'll be able to access the values in a more object oriented way like the syntax in your question.

Comment: I did leave out the true parameter of the json_decode() but an error comes saying 'Trying to get property of non-object'. Any help?

Comment: If you pass true, you'll get an array. For that you use the square brackets. If it's not an array, its an object and for that you use the  `->` syntax.

Comment: It seems that i've figured out my problem. Instead of having '$status->data->message', it should be $status->data[0]->message. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Ahh yes.. I usually take the data parameter out right away... I forgot it's formatted like that... Glad to help, happy coding!